# Excel: return all values which have an error in the same row

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel structure:

```
A1: Item 1
A2: Item 2
A3: Item 3
A4: Item 4

B1: some value
B2: #N/A
B3: #N/A
B4: some other value
```

I would need an array formula which would return the following:

```
C1: Item 2
C2: Item 3
```

My first try was to use something like this:

```
{=INDEX(A:A;MATCH(???;B:B;0))}
```

Problem is, no idea how to look for #N/A in the MATCH function so I changed my data to show "0" instead of #N/A. Then I adapted the formula as such:

```
{=INDEX(A:A;MATCH("0";B:B;0))}
```

Once I enter the formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, I only get the first value (Item 2). How can I get both?

Thanks,
Mircea

Comment: Why not do this: Your `#N/A` values are coming from a formula.  Wrap `Iferror()` around it (i.e. `=IfError([your whole formula], "Error")`) Then use Index/Match, looking for "Error". (Edit: This won't work completely, since Index/Match returns the first match, unless you have other info to look up. Give me a second, I have a solution).

Comment: Did either of the formulas below work for you? If so please mark the one that worked as correct. It is something only you can do. It will mark the question as answered. If they did not work, some feedback will help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 2010 or later than use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$4)/(ISERROR($B$1:$B$4)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

If you have 2007 or earlier than use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,SMALL(IF((ISERROR($B$1:$B$4)),ROW($1:$4)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed by Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Change the 4's to the last row of your data.

Copy down as far as you need.  In the photo the formula goes through the forth row.

[image]

Comment: I was just thinking you would have the solution to this problem - based on what you have posted in the past :)

Comment: Aw man, you're just a tad quicker. Nicely done. I'll post my solution anyways, it does the same but I *really* need to learn `Aggregate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Mine does pretty much like @ScottCraner's, and I just thought I'd post it here FYI (I like his solution more though, IMO, since you don't have to edit the other formula too):

Wrap `IfError()` around your formula that's returning the `#N/A` error: `=IfError([your formula],"Error")` then

With your data in A1:B4 (like Scott's screenshot), enter this in E1:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$4,SMALL(IF(B$1:B$4="Error",ROW(B$1:B$4)-ROW(B$1)+1),ROWS(B$1:B1))),"")`

Enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> and drag down a ways.

edit: If anyone has a tip on how to not have to require the `IsError()` edit, I'd be appreciative!

Edit2: Ah, got it thanks to Scott's answer. **You can use this formula without editing the original to include an `IfError()`**:
 `=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$4,SMALL(IF(ISERROR($B$1:$B$4),ROW(B$1:B$4)-ROW(B$1)+1),ROWS(B$1:B1))),"")`